# Put file at specific port on Localhost

Tags: asp.net, development-environment, localhost

I need to put a file at this address: http://localhost:51547/file.txt

What folder would I put it in on C:/?

Tony

Comment: This port is used by ASP.NET Development Server.  Not IIS.

Comment: Things that are not specified in the question should not be implied in the answer.

Comment: I am sure following link can help you people: http://withasp.net/specific-port-on-local-host/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and you're trying to expose a file via the ASP.NET development server at that location (http://localhost:51547/file.txt) I'm afraid the answer is not quite to your liking.

Basically I don't think you can serve files from the root of the ASP.NET development server (i.e right after the *localhost:port/* part - the port is automatically selected by ASP but you can also manually configure it). ASP.NET automatically creates a virtual application path right after *localhost:por>* and so you're most likely going to be limited to serving files from the virtual application folder. So, assuming you web application name is: "testApp", if you put a file called *file.txt* in the directory where you're storing the source code for "testApp" it will also become available when you're testing at: `http://localhost:port/testApp/file.txt` (note the *testApp* in between the host-name & port, and the file-name)

**UPDATE**

In light of you comment, here's something you could do. You could try to get a simple HTTP server installed on your development computer and have it serve files on a different port (say port 8000). In that case you would serve `file.txt` using this secondary HTTP server and it would be accessible at: `http://localhost:8000/file.txt`.

You could try to install Apache or use IIS which comes with Windows. For Apache, the quickest way to get it going would be to install a [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) environment. You may also try [Lighttpd](http://www.kevinworthington.com/lighttpd-for-windows/#), and also note that MySQL or PHP are not required at all if you're only serving static files.

Comment: Dear Miky D,

Your answer totally makes sense.  But let me explain what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to get a WCF service make a cross domain call to a Sl3 app.  Per MSDN references you're supposed to put the crossdomain.xml at the root of the domain, but I cannot seem to do that, as it puts it at localhost:51547/myservice/crossdomain.xml.  The service however doesn't find the file at that location.  HTTP 404 error returned.  Any ideas? or is my explanation insufficent?

Answer (score 0):

Any folder you want. The port designator is specified in IIS itself.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you that if you want to do a site(HTTP) is better to use the port 80 or to do a redirection for another port, remember too that localhoost is a loop back and also take a look at [PortForward](http://portforward.com/cports.htm) to check some ports that are used by specific applications and types of servers, and please improve your question.

Regards.